# How to use default arguments in php

Tags: php, default-value, function-call

I want to define a function `doSomething(arg1, arg2)` with default values to arg1=val and arg2=val

When I write

```
function doSomething($arg1="value1", $arg2="value2"){
 // do something
}
```

Is it possible now to call doSomething with default arg1 and arg2="new_value2"

Comment: C# 4.0 offers something similar called `Optional Parameters` move over to ASP.Net 4.0 ;)

Comment: Many languages offer something called `named parameters` where you could, as a PHP example, call `doSomething($arg2="value2")`. This is valid PHP syntax but do not be fooled into thinking it works as a named parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, sadly, this is not possible. If you define `$arg2`, you will need to define `$arg1` as well.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes if I have a lot of parameters with defaults, I'll use an array to contain the arguments and merge it with defaults.

```
public function doSomething($requiredArg, $optional = array())
{
   $defaults = array(
      'arg1' => 'default',
      'arg2' -> 'default'
   );

   $options = array_merge($defaults, $optional);
}
```

Really only makes sense if you have a lot of arguments though.

Answer (score 3):

```
function doSomething( $arg1, $arg2 ) {
  if( $arg1 === NULL ) $arg1 = "value1";
  if( $arg2 === NULL ) $arg2 = "value2";
  ...
}
```

And to call:

```
doSomething();
doSomething(NULL, "notDefault");
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround but using NULL to signify the default value may not be a good idea - after all, NULL could be a valid argument in itself. Another option would be to define a "default" constant containing something totally outlandish like `^^^^^^^-----DEFAULT----^^^^^^^^^^` to use instead. You could then `doSomething(default, "notDefault");`

Answer (score 2):

Do you ever assign arg1 but not arg2?  If not then I'd switch the order.